# Find the right triangle number

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Here is my first try at a puzzle. Find the missing number.

```
            7
          5 2 6
        2 0 9 7 6
      1 4 2 7 6 7 9
    4 7 6 3 3 2 6 9 8
  5 1 9 2 7 6 6 9 8 2 8 
6 1 6 5 3 2 9 7 9 7 8 6 ?
```

Hint:

> the title is a hint

Hint:

> almost half of the numbers should be discarded!

Hint:

> you are not looking for a number at all but a hidden text

Hint:

> Numbers come in pairs

Comment: Right triangle 90 degrees then take out the 0 and  left with 9?

Comment: I think this puzzle is way too hard. Added another hint :)

Comment: I don't know if this changes anything, but is it a Isosceles triangle? @filip

Comment: @Duck Thats a bingo!

Comment: Yay! Now gonna rot 13 it

Comment: Svaq gur yrsg cbegvba naq qvfpneq vg. Xrrc gur zvqqyr bar gubhtu- rot 13

Comment: @Duck I think I missunderstood what you meant. I will supply another hint.

Comment: Then how come it said look for the missing number

Comment: @Duck it is a missing number that completes the hidden text

Comment: Ohhhhh, that makes way more sense

Comment: I've been totally stuck for 5 days, but this last hint really helped @filip! Great puzzle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing number is

> 9.

This is because when you

> Take the right half of the triangle numbers, you are left with a sequence as follows: 72 69 76 76 79 32 69 86 69 82 89 79 78 6? when you group them into pairs.

When

> translating ASCII codes to symbols, you get the phrase HELLO EVERYON?. The question mark should obviously be an E, which translates to ASCII code 69, meaning the question mark ought to be a 9.

Comment: YES! Great job, this one was very dififcult :D

Comment: Thanks! The last hint was a lifesaver, wouldn't have gotten anywhere without it! :D

Answer (score 0):

> Discard the left half but keep the middle column. I kind of identified two patterns and therefore I think it can be a 5, if not a 7